# Open CL with AMD

Tags: opencl

I am trying to implement matrix multiplication usign OpenCL. I have an ATI Radeon HD Radeon 5000 series graphics card.
This is one of the programs i found on the net, but linking errors are coming which i am not able to solve.

I tried running the code mentioned in this site
http://gpgpu-computing4.blogspot.in/2009/10/matrix-multiplication-3-opencl.html

I followed setting up my visual studio project from this site

```
        http://www.guineacode.com/2010/linking-and-compiling-opencl/
```

but the following errors come

```
      error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _oclLoadProgSource referenced in function _main
      error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _shrLogEx referenced in function "void __cdecl       __shrCheckErrorEX(int,int,void (__cdecl*)(int),char const *,int)" (?__shrCheckErrorEX@@YAXHHP6AXH@ZPBDH@Z)
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: You probably are not linking `OpenCL.lib` and `shrUtils.lib`. The OpenCL library needs to be added as a link component in your project. I can't help with how to do that in Visual Studio, unfortunately. For `shrUtils` it might be more complicated - AFAIK it is an internal NVIDIA OpenCL SDK component, so you might need to get their SDK code and compile it to a library yourself, then link against it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Can you try this ?

1. Make sure you have the latest Catalyst driver from AMD.
2. Try downloading AMD APP SDK 2.6 from here : http://developer.amd.com/sdks/AMDAPPSDK/downloads/Pages/default.aspx
3. After the install, do the following
   Make sure to include $(AMDAPPSDKROOT)\include for header files
   Library Directory : $(AMDAPPSDKROOT)\lib\x86 or x86_64 depending on your bitness

4.Now you can build and run the program

Here is an older post which talks about linking 2.4... with slight modification you can use the instruction
http://blog.cuvilib.com/2011/07/01/how-to-run-opencl-in-microsoft-vs-2008-using-amd-app-sdk/

If you are looking only MatrixMultiplication sample, AMD APP SDK bundles some samples along with pack you can find them in (Windows)
C:\USERS\%USER%\My Documents\AMD APP\ Samples
and in Linux under
/opt/AMD APP SDK/Samples

HTH