# Adding include directory in visual studio for Opencl

Tags: visual-studio, include, opencl

I found this example on this link : 
http://gpgpu-computing4.blogspot.com/2009/10/matrix-multiplication-3-opencl.html

and I am trying to test it in visual studio 2015 but unfortunately this error is appearing **`identifier "shrCheckError" is undefined`** when i'm looking for the solution i found that i should download some source codes from here https://developer.nvidia.com/opencl 
 So i download zip file its name is OpenCL Matrix Multiplication from the website but how can i install it into visual studio or how can i call #include <oclUtils.h>

Comment: Look here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57017982/9178992

Comment: @ProjectPhysX I still have one problem `unresolved external symbol shrLogEx referenced in function "void __cdecl __shrCheckErrorEX(int,int,void (__cdecl*)(int),char const *,int)" (?__shrCheckErrorEX@@YAXHHP6AXH@ZPEBDH@Z)` i don't know what i missed any suggestion please ?

Comment: That is a linker error. Maybe look into the code to see what the __shrCheckErrorEX function does and where it is called from. If it is not mandatory, comment it out. See also here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9699111/9178992